# get data from a column then select whole row where the data belongs

Tags: java, swing, oop, user-interface, jtable

for example this is my `JTable`:

> ID|NAME|AGE
>
> 001|anna|18
>
> 002|tony|25

now i want that the user will enter the ID, then convert that ID into which row it belongs. now i'm using `setRowSelectionInterval()` to select the row without really selecting it in the actual row. but i don't know how to get the data from a column, then convert it into a row where it belongs, so i can put in in the `setRowSelectionInterval()`. thank you for any of your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a loop.

1. You can use the `getRowCount()` method of the table to iterate through each row.
2. Then you use the `getValueAt(...)` method to get the value of the ID in the row for the specific column.
3. When you find a match you use the row index for the `setRowSelectionInterval(...)` method.